# How to show the existence of the following number $h$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f$ be a function defined on $ [a,b]$, $f$ measurable. Then we define metric mean $h$ of $f$ is a real number such that $$\mu \{ x: \ f(x) \geq h \} \geq \frac{b-a}{2}$$ and $$\mu \{ x: \ f(x) > h \} <\frac{b-a}{2}$$

Now from above two conditions how can we prove that

1) existence of $h$ for each $f$.

2) Uniqueness of $h$ for each $f$.

where $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Isn't the first inequality equivalent to the second? And surely we need to define the "metric mean" to be the **smallest** $h$ satisfying these inequalities? By the way, where did you encounter this?

Comment: I encountered this in a research paper of $1934$ of approximation theory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We define the function

$$g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0, b-a], \ g(y)=\mu(\{x\in [a,b]: f(x) \geq y \})=\mu(f^{-1}([h,\infty)).$$

We have that $g$ is monoton decreasing, upper semicontinuous as

$$ \lim_{h\uparrow h_0} g(h)= \lim_{h\uparrow h_0} \mu(f^{-1}([h,\infty)) = \mu(f^{-1}[h_0,\infty)) $$

and

$$ \lim_{h\downarrow h_0} g(h) = \lim_{h\uparrow h_0} \mu(f^{-1}([h,\infty)) = \mu(f^{-1}(h_0,\infty)) =  g(h)- \mu(f^{-1}(\{h_0 \})).$$

Furthermore, we have

$$ \lim_{y\rightarrow -\infty} g(y)=0, \quad \lim_{y\rightarrow \infty} g(y)=b-a .$$

Thus, there exists a unique $h\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(h)\geq \frac{b-a}{2}$ and $g(h+\epsilon)<\frac{b-a}{2}$ for every $\epsilon>0$. This $h$ is the one you are looking for.

Comment: But can you find out $h$ for the function $f(x) = x$ defined on $[0,2]$.

Comment: In the proof the term $g(h+\epsilon) < \frac{b-a}{2}$ doesn't implies $\mu \{ x: \ f(x) > h \} <\frac{b-a}{2}$$

Comment: So i think such an $h$ may not exist always. Because for $f(x) = x$ there is no such $h$.

Comment: Can you tell me where the confusion is?

Comment: You are right, I think one should modify the definition to $\mu(\{ x\in [a,b] : f(x)\geq h + \epsilon \})< \frac{b-a}{2}$ for every $\epsilon > 0$. Otherwise we cannot (in general) fulfill the second condition. An alternative would be to choose the largest $h$ such that the first inequality holds.

Comment: Exactly. Thanks